# Список секций по умолчанию в .config файле?

Tags: .net

Как определить **текущий** список секций конфигураций по умолчанию в конфиг файле (*.exe.config или web.config) .NET приложения? Таких как appSettings?

Comment: Э... Что такое "*текущий* список секций *по умолчанию*"?

Comment: @Athari ну секции, как appSettings, connectionStrings, system.diagnostics или system.web. Текущий - это значит его можно подправить.

Comment: Как подправить? Что именно вы хотите сделать? И что значит "по умолчанию"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Список секций по умолчанию находится в файле конфигурации на уровне компьютера или сервера.

И если вы получаете в приложение такое вот сообщение:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.diagnostics.

Вполне возможно, что кто-то подпортил вам machine.config файл. В данном случае стерли объявление секции system.diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

```
My.Settings.Properties...
```

возвращает коллекцию свойств-параметров в программе-оболочке

Comment: насколько я знаю, `My.Settings.Properties` является особенностью проектов для VB.NET, кодируется в скрытом классе Settings.Designer.vb и имеет отношение к вкладке Settings в свойствах VB.NET проекта. Не так ли?

Comment: Верно подмечено.
можно создать отдельный файл, и назначить его переменной, он ведь как класс создается. (Dim s As Settings1)
Если нужен не VB.NET то можно поискать на MSDN как оно там делается в других .NET языках